# remove sub string with inside special characters in php/wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Given string is

```
» Categories » Consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod
```

I want to exclude a substring

```
» Categories »
```

from given string.

I tried this without success:

```
$string = "» Categories » Consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod";
echo str_replace('» Categories »', '', $string);
```

Note: I am using core php in wordpress

Comment: Strange, it works for me! Can i ask what version of PHP you are using please

Comment: That code works as expected: https://3v4l.org/5GvWH

Comment: This is working for me. Please put some more information about the error.

Comment: Its working fine for me.

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: @Fergal Andrews, just not working.

Comment: @RiggsFolly, PHP Version 5.6.25

Comment: Works fine in that version also. Very strange

Comment: echo is_callable('str_replace') ? true : false;

Comment: $string = mb_convert_encoding("» Categories » Consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod",'UTF-8');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly sure what your use case is, but I ran into a similar problem a while ago, which was caused by HTML entities.

It took me longer than I care to admit to spot the issue, due to my output showing the decoded character (`»`) character, whilst my PHP function was receiving the encoded character(`&raquo;` or `&#187;`) instead.

The solution was essentially to use [html_entity_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) or [htmlspecialchars_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php) to decode your string before running `str_replace` like this:

```
$string = "» Categories » Consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod";
$decoded = htmlspecialchars_decode($string);
// $decoded = html_entity_decode($string); //If you want to use html_entity_decode instead
echo str_replace('» Categories »', '', $decoded);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
preg_replace('/» \w+ »\s+/', '', $string)
```

Comment: works great, but why load the regex engine to do what `str_replace()` does quite happily

Answer (score 2):

Just use regular expression:

```
/\»(.*?)\» /
```

This will select everything between characters ».

```
$string = "» Categories » Consectetur adipiscing elit sed do eiusmod";

echo preg_replace('/\»(.*?)\» /', '', $string);
```

Comment: works great, but why load the regex engine to do what `str_replace()` does quite happily